# How can i use a library inside a podfile?

Tags: cocoapods, podfile

Can i use a library inside a pod file ? For example ,i would like to use some functionality from https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability inside a pod file of this https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit

Comment: Unless you control the podspec, I'd say there are little chances you can do this. Unless you manipulate Podfile, which might be hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you don't modify code of external libraries. When you import something to use it in your project via CocoaPods or any other dependency manager you use items provided by the library in **your** project. Meaning your classes rely on some behaviour from them. You should not make external libraries depend on other external libraries but you combine their logic in your custom classes.